# How to clip a view only the left and right sides?

Tags: swift, clip

I want to clip only left and right side of subviews on a view.
So, there is subviews's content on the top and bottom over super view.
How can I do it?

Comment: Have you consider using a `CALayer` mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`mask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410861-mask) property of the main layer of the parent view:

```
// The mask has the same width as parentView but much taller. It is not visible
// by itself so so can set `dy` to any value. Negative values for `dy` means
// making it grow in height
let maskRect = parentView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -1000)

let maskPath = UIBezierPath(rect: maskRect)
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

// The color is not important here, its opacity matters more. Opaque or
// partially-opaque pixels in the mask will allow subviews to show through.
// Fully transparent pixels will hide it. Kinda backwards if you ask me
maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
parentView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Here's a couple of illustrations. `parentView` is the black wireframe.

No mask:

[image: No mask]

With mask (clipping on left and right sides only):

[image: With mask - clipping on left and right]